# How to merge multiple geotiffs by the maximum value using gdal_merge.py?

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, image-mosaic, gdal-merge

I'm try to use the gdal_merge.py to generate a a big composite image considering the maximum value per pixel (to avoid the no data value).

But I didn't find this option for gdal_merge.py.
My code is:

```
python gdal_merge -o mergedLayerOutput.tif -q -v --optfile filesToMerge.txt
```

The result:
[image: Result of the merge of MODIS images]

Any suggestion about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are trying to ignore the NoData values in the input rasters, I suggest you either set the NoData for each raster before merging (in which case `gdal_merge.py` will ignore those pixels on merging) or use the `-n` [option](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) to supply such a value at the execution call time.